# Node with + Character

Tags: vapor

I am making a request using the Vapor HTTP Client and the request needs to have form URL encoded data in the body which has a + character in it. When the request is sent the + character is removed.

```
request.formURLEncoded = try Node(node: [
            "From": "+18881002000"
])
let response = try drop.client.respond(to: request)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in [Vapor 2.1.2](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/releases/tag/2.1.2).